# Want to create if-statement, followed by several else-if statements and lastly a "capture-all" else-statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Creating a "pirate dialogue" with the option of choosing the left or right hand. I want it to answer positively on different spellings of "left" and "right" (as you will see in code) however, when I add the final "else" code for all inputs that aren't "right" or "left", it gives me an "java.lang.Error", unreachable code. I tested my code before I added the final "else" statement and it works just as I want it to, added the "else" statement again and it gives me the same error.

(I would also appreciate tips and feedback on how to improve my code, this is the second project I have ever created by myself entirely)

Anyways, here's the code:

```
package myOwn;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class myArms {

static Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    armInput();
}

public static void armInput() {
    System.out.println("Behold the arms! Which hand holds the secret item?");
    String answer = sc2.nextLine();
    System.out.println(armOpener(answer));
}

public static String armOpener(String answer) {
    if(answer.equals("left")) {
        return "Aha! Indeed the gemstone was hidden in the left hand. Now...";
    }else if(answer.equals("Left")) {
        return "Aha! Indeed the gemstone was hidden in the left hand. Now...";
    }else if(answer.equals("LEFT")) {
        return "Aha! Indeed the gemstone was hidden in the left hand. Now...";
    }else if(answer.equals("right")) {
        return "Bummer! The treasure was in the other hand. Easy for me to say, huh? What if there wasn't a treasure from the start of? Who knows...";
    }else if(answer.equals("Right")) {
        return "Bummer! The treasure was in the other hand. Easy for me to say, huh? What if there wasn't a treasure from the start of? Who knows...";
    }else if(answer.equals("RIGHT")) {
        return "Bummer! The treasure was in the other hand. Easy for me to say, huh? What if there wasn't a treasure from the start of? Who knows...";
    }else {
        return "Did you not hear me boy? I'm asking you, which hand?!";
    }
    return answer;
}
```

}

The line "return answer;" is the one that ends up with a red underline. The red underline goes away if I remove the last "else"-statement.

Comment: So? Do you want to return `answer` if none of the `if`s match or do you want to return `"Did you not hear me boy? I'm asking you, which hand?!"`. Because right now your code attempts to do both.

Comment: *Unrelated:* You can simplify your code by calling [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) instead of `equals`.

Comment: the red underline is probably saying something like "unreachable code" since that statement can never be executed since returning in an `if` or `else` block

Comment: Your `if else` statement is exhaustive so the last `return answer;` will never be reached. Just remove it.

Comment: A `return` statement ends execution of the method.  There are no circumstances in which execution can reach the `return answer;` line, because it will always encounter another `return` statement first.

Comment: Incidentally, there's an `equalsIgnoreCase` method that you can use instead of `equals`, to do a case-insensitive comparison.  That will let you cut down the number of `if` statements.

Comment: Feel so stupid as to the solution (to just remove the "return answer;") but I'll read your other inputs for further progression. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because after all your `if` statements, you have a `return` statement which will never be executed since, if none of the `if` statements match, it will go to the `else` statement and terminate there.

You can either remove the `return` line or the final `else` depending on the expected return value if none of the conditions are met.

```
...
public static String armOpener(String answer) {
    String ans = answer.toLowerCase();

    if (ans.equals("left")) {
        return "Aha! Indeed the gemstone was hidden in the left hand. Now...";
    } else if (ans.equals("right")) {
        return "Bummer! The treasure was in the other hand. Easy for me to say, huh? What if there wasn't a treasure from the start of? Who knows...";
    }

    return "Did you not hear me boy? I'm asking you, which hand?!";
}
...
```

Also, it appears that you are returning the same value for different letter cases of the words (`right` and `RIGHT`) which can be handled in one statement by comparing the lower case value of the variable. Then when you have multiple if's like that, you can simplify that by using a `switch` statement:

```
...
public static String armOpener(String answer) {
    switch(answer.toLowerCase()) {
        case "left":
            return "Aha! Indeed the gemstone was hidden in the left hand. Now...";

        case "right":
            return "Bummer! The treasure was in the other hand. Easy for me to say, huh? What if there wasn't a treasure from the start of? Who knows...";

        default:
            return "Did you not hear me boy? I'm asking you, which hand?!";
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I ended up just removing the line "return answer;" at the end, as well as simplifying the code with "(answer.equalsIgnoreCase)", which led the final result somewhat similar to yours but without the use of a switch-statement, of which I am not familiar with yet :)

Comment: @martyro Great, at least you found a solution that works for you.